# Has Batman ever died and been resurrected?

Tags: dc, comics, batman

Many of the superheroes have died and been resurrected in both DC and Marvel several times.

But has that ever happened to Batman?

Comment: Are you asking if batman has died in one comic and been alive in the next? Or specifically been resurrected after dying in the same comic?

Comment: died in one comic and been alive in other comic !

Comment: [He has died in one continuity, Earth-Two](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Bruce_Wayne_(Earth-Two)#Death), but stayed alive in Earth-One. So that counts?

Comment: the comic "Whatever Happened to the Caped Crusader?" comes to my mind but is not in the continuity

Comment: Didn't he die in Endgame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this article on screenrant](http://screenrant.com/most-resurrected-superheroes-back-from-the-dead-comic-book-characters-ever-all-time/?view=all), they list Batman as the 11th most resurrected superhero. Whether this is an exhaustive list or just a few mentions, I was unable to find much else so here we go in chronological order.

<sub>Click on the images to see them in full size!</sub>

#### [Brave and the Bold Vol 1](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Brave_and_the_Bold_Vol_1)

Batman was resurrected for the first time in the 115th issue of Brave and the Bold in November, 1974. He was electrocuted by a booby trap set by Bugsy Cathart. The doctors pronounce him dead, however Ray Palmer (as Atom) decides to help Batman solve his last case by controlling his brain (by physically running around in it), a la Ratatouille.

[image: Batman getting electrocuted] [image: Doctors pronounce batman dead]
[image: Atom running around in Batman's brain]

#### [Batman: Birth of the Demon](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman:_Birth_of_the_Demon)

The next time Batman came back from the dead was in December, 1992. After being impaled (by a shovel) Batman fights on and falls into the Lazarus pit with Ra's. After being buried by a sandstorm, only Batman seems to survive.

[image: Batman and Ra's fall into the Lazarus Pit] [image: Batman climbs out of the sand.]

#### [Superman: Emperor Joker](http://joker.wikia.com/wiki/Emperor_Joker_(Storyline))

The third time Batman is resurrected, he gets resurrected a lot. Like *a lot* a lot. After the Joker becomes the Emperor Joker, a form of Joker with reality-altering powers, he repeatedly kills Batman, only to resurrect him to kill him again. Superman eventually defeats the Joker by making him realize he has an obsession with Batman, because of which he can't erase Batman forever, despite his omnipotence. After Superman finally manages to fix reality, Spectre reveals there's nothing he can do to erase the countless horrible deaths Batman had to endure all this time, and that someone will have to carry them in his stead. At first, it sounds like Superman is about to carry all the burden, but the story ends with Batman admitting he's had the best night sleep ever, whilst the Joker is shown in a catatonic state and drooling on the floor in one of Arkham's cells, implying he inherited the memories of the countless deaths Batman had to endure.

[image: Superman carries Batman's memories]

#### [Final Crisis Vol 1](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Crisis_Vol_1)

The most recent time Batman's been resurrected was in Final Crisis Vol 1, at the hands of Darkseid, after attempting to shoot him, Batman get's vaporised by his Omega Beams. However, Batman simply was shot into the past, and after lying his utility belt on Anthro's dying body begins to draw a cave painting.

[image: Superman holding Batman's corpse] [image: Batman alive in the past.]

Comment: Holy tiny panels, Batman. Where are my [Bat-Noculars](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v123/apennyworth/batman/miscpixs/BatnocularsBamanGreenHornet5.jpg~original)?

Comment: Wasn't Batman resurrected during Blackest Night? I'm not really a comic buff, so I'm pretty fuzzy on things, but I thought he became a Black Lantern because he had died.

Comment: @Ellesedil Neither am I as you might be able to tell from my name

Comment: You would be correct, although he's less resurrected and more reanimated for a period.

Comment: @Valorum click to open the large version